# How to route vimeo style URL in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, vimeo

I am new to Rails.

I want to have a cool URL like vimeo, but do not know how to do it in Rails!

http://vimeo.com/30806583

I have searched around for two days already, only found rails vanity URL technique or friendlyID on github, which could potentially help.

But I still have no idea for how to implement it in Rails app.

Thanks!

Comment: What I am meaning cool URL is that most of websists use such following URLs like http://vimeo.com/video/30806583  Vimeo simplified it to http://vimeo.com/30806583

Answer (score 2):

See the [routing guide section on segment constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints). There's nothing to prevent you from matching "/:id" with a reasonable-looking constraint and routing it to whatever controller you want.